# Get pictures from facebook in ListView?

Tags: android, facebook, listview, sdk, image

I'm trying to get the user's friends pictures and show them in a ListView next to the friend's name.
I don't know if I'm implementing the code right, but when I run my project I only get the friendlist names, and the ImageView appears empty? It doesn't show anything.

Here is my code, sorry if I'm doing everything wrong here, I'm still learning:

**This is my custom ArrayAdapter:**

The objects[] parameter is an array with all the user's friends names
and the pics[] is a Bitmap array which contains the user's friends profile pictures.

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, Bitmap[] pics) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    c = context;
    res = resource;
    viewresourceid= textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.pics = pics;
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
      c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendslistlayout, parent, false);
      TextView fname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.friendname);
      ImageView fpic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.friendpic);
     return rowView;
}
```

I read somewhere that using a AsyncTask class could take care of the problem of the ListView updating and lagging. So I created this one, I send the user's friends name (f) and the user's friends pictures (p), and call the adapter, which is above:

```
public class FImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object[],Void,FriendsAdapter>{

    @Override
    protected FriendsAdapter doInBackground(Object[]... params) {

        String[] f = (String[]) params[0];
        Bitmap[] p = (Bitmap[]) params[1];

        FriendsAdapter FRIENDS = new FriendsAdapter(Friends.this,R.layout.friendslistlayout,R.id.friendname,f,p);
        return FRIENDS;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FriendsAdapter o){
        o.notifyDataSetChanged();
        friends.setAdapter(o);
    }
}
```

And I have this in my onComplete method in a requestListener, which is the one making the FB.request("me/friends") call.

```
Friends.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new FImageLoader().execute(friendsarray,friendsp);
                }

            });
```

It's really a bunch of code, I hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:** Turns out, my friendsp array, the one with all the bitmap pictures, was being passed null, I fixed it and now the pictures are shown.

Now I have another problem, the pictures are taking a long time to load, since they're being retrieved directly from the web.
How could I fix that, I'm thinking about saving them like in a cache, but I really have no idea on how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Universal Image Loader library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) on github. It lets you download images from urls and cache them. The source for this project is a good starting point if you want to write your own cache. The sample project comes with a [ListView example](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/UniversalImageLoaderExample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader/ImageListActivity.java). The library is written by [Sergey Tarasevich](https://github.com/nostra13).

There is also [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) by [Fedor Vlasov](https://github.com/thest1) which provides a similar functionality: to allow you to download images asynchronously from urls and cache them. Universal Image Loader is based on LazyList.